# Arduino beginner LCD question - best way to connect to pins?

Tags: arduino

I just received my first Arduino kit today - it wasn't hard to make my first LCD chaser - woot!  Already I am on to better things.

I want to mess with the [EL1602A LCD](http://www.emartee.com/product/41872/Arduino%20Serial%20LCD%201602%20Shield) screen next.  What's the best way to connect to the pins?  They look enticingly solderable so that I end up with jumper leads hanging permanently off, but is that a good idea?

If not, what do people suggest?

Comment: What board do you have? Pro?

Comment: Arduino is an ATmega1280.  LCD is an Elatec EL1602

Comment: What Arduino kit exactly? Link?

Comment: Ummm...why does it matter what kit?  An EL1602 is an EL1602 is an EL1602

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find pictures of this part of yours (didn't look too hard). But if there are holes in it (that's what comes to my mind when I hear "enticingly solderable" :)) - through hole soldering ready - what I usually do is solder it with break away header pins ([like this](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10158)) so it can be easily seated on a breadboard.

Comment: I could only find a PDF data sheet which isn't very clear.  But yes, I think this might be the way to do it - see what else people come up with.  Since I am just getting into this, the obvious solution wasn't so obvious to me.

Comment: Ahhh here we go. http://www.fisnet.ru/techdocs/lcd/elatec.pdf     

The image on the title page is indicative of what I have.

Comment: Yah, looks like the right kind of holes, if you know what I mean :D Not sure how "obvious" this is, someone else might want to use female pins (they're good for use with wires). But that's what works best for me :)

Comment: I got some pins, soldered them in and the thing half worked.  I could light it up, I could send to it but it was gibberish.  After a couple of days of frustration I had a close look at the soldering and thought...hmmm...that one looks a bit dodgy.  Eureka!!!  It works.  Thanks for all input.

Comment: Very welcome. Good luck with those crystals ;)